# What do you call a young person who studies and works in a different city, but hasn't bought a home but tries to stay there?

Tags: word-choice

Can you call somebody a "New York drifter" or "Hong Kong drifter" to describe a person who strives to settle there, living alone and working hard?

Comment: **"How** do you describe a young person who **studies and works**..." I wouldn't call them a drifter if they are studying in one place. A drifter moves from place to place.

Comment: Is there a word for that in your language? If so, how do dictionaries translate it into English? If not, why do you think there's a word like that in English?

Comment: "hasn't bought a home but tries to stay there" could mean someone who's rented for years (in a rent-controlled apartment they could be there for decades), or someone who's sleeping on a park bench. You wouldn't describe them in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

A drifter is someone who moves about, without any aim or purpose. They might move from one city to another, and from one job to another without any real plan. The jobs are probably low-skill and low-pay.

So "Drifter" doesn't fit this sense at all.

I suppose you could call a person who wants to move to New York, an "aspiring New-Yorker". This doesn't imply that they live alone, nor does it mean that they work hard. I doubt there is a single word with all three meanings, and drifter certainly isn't right.